# How to generate the BOM structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a array like:

```
array = ['aa:0','bb:1', 'cc_a:2', 'cc_a:2', 
      'cc_b:2', 'cc_b:2', 'cc_b:2', 
      'cc_b:2', 'cc_c:2', 'cc_c:2', 
      'cc_c:2', 'cc_c:2', 'cc_d:2', 
      'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 
      'cc_c:3', 'ee:3','cc_d:2', 
      'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 
      'cc_c:3', 'ee:2','dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3']
```

want to print like:

```
"""
aa:0x1
**bb:1x1
****cc_a:2x2
****cc_b:2x4
****cc_c:2x4
****cc_d:2x2
******dd_a:3x3
******cc_c:3x1
****ee:2x1
******dd_a:3x3
"""
```

cc_a:2x2
cc_a is number,2 is depth, x2 is the quantity

I have build a tree by python, but have a idea about calculate the quantity.

```
array = ['aa:0','bb:1', 'cc_a:2', 'cc_a:2', 
      'cc_b:2', 'cc_b:2', 'cc_b:2', 
      'cc_b:2', 'cc_c:2', 'cc_c:2', 
      'cc_c:2', 'cc_c:2', 'cc_d:2', 
      'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 
      'cc_c:3', 'ee:3','cc_d:2', 
      'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 
      'cc_c:3', 'ee:2','dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3']

class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []

def build_tree(arr):
    root_node = None
    counter = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for item in arr:
        name,depth = item.strip().split(':')
        if depth == '0':
            root_node = TreeNode(name)
            counter[depth].append(root_node)
        else:
            father = counter[str(int(depth)-1)][-1]
            child = TreeNode(name)
            father.children.append(child)
            counter[depth].append(child)   
    return root_node

tree = build_tree(array)

def dfs(node,depth):
    if not node:
        return
    print ("**"*depth+node.name)
    for c in node.children:
        dfs(c,depth+1)          
dfs(tree,0)
```

```
print:
aa
**bb
****cc_a
****cc_a
****cc_b
****cc_b
****cc_b
****cc_b
****cc_c
****cc_c
****cc_c
****cc_c
****cc_d
******dd_a
******dd_a
******dd_a
******cc_c
******ee
****cc_d
******dd_a
******dd_a
******dd_a
******cc_c
****ee
******dd_a
******dd_a
******dd_a

want to print like:
aa:0x1
**bb:1x1
****cc_a:2x2
****cc_b:2x4
****cc_c:2x4
****cc_d:2x2
******dd_a:3x3
******cc_c:3x1
****ee:2x1
******dd_a:3x3
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer, it is more a comment than an answer.
You speak about a tree, with Parent/Child structure.
But in the array, I see no parent/child relationship !!!
Could you explain more clearly how you make the parent/child structure in your array ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ['aa:0','bb:1', 'cc_a:2', 'cc_b:2' means, bb's father is aa, bb's children is cc_a, cc_a's sibling is cc_b, the number after ":" is the depth.

Comment: I saw that there is the idea of level. You mean that when the level changes, the change of level means that the parent is the upper, and the next level is the child ?  Example : 'cc_d:2', 
      'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 'dd_a:3', 
      'cc_c:3', 'ee:3', means the cc_d is parent and all the others children ? My comment, is to use the most common way to modelize parent/child relationship, (parent, child), this is only an advice.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the upper level maybe his father or sibling, it depends on the number after ":",  if the number of next level is smaller than it, it means next level is his father's sibling.

Comment: your need is at first a kind of select distinct, and sum for items having the same name, and level, and successive like that dd_a:3 is repeated 3 times. I mean that you should pre-process your array, to reduce your data, and like that, things become clearer for you.